# MYSQL: transpose the result of a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

please I have problem with transposing an sql query result.
My sql query is:

```
SELECT atop.name AS top, aseco.name AS abei, aseco.abeiId AS CI, aseco.location AS pac, axrt.frk AS FRK
FROM atop INNER JOIN (aseco INNER JOIN axrt ON (aseco.abeiId = axrt.abeiId) AND (aseco.BCFId = axrt.BCFId) AND (aseco.topId = axrt.topId)) ON atop.topId = aseco.topId
WHERE (((axrt.ctp)<>8) AND ((aseco.abeiish)=5)) OR (((axrt.ctp)<>3) AND ((aseco.abeiish)=2) AND ((aseco.hpnmd)=2));
```

the result is like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
top       |   abei      |         CI   |    pac    |  FRK      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
A         |     b       |       e      |     1     |    12     |
A         |     b       |       e      |     1     |    13     |
A         |     b       |       e      |     1     |    14     |
A         |     c       |       t      |     2     |    45     |
A         |     c       |       t      |     2     |    56     |
A         |     c       |       t      |     2     |    23     |
A         |     c       |       t      |     2     |    29     |
A         |     c       |       t      |     2     |    50     |
b         |     c       |       t      |     1     |    11     |
b         |     c       |       t      |     1     |    56     |
b         |     c       |       t      |     1     |    78     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to transpose this result and I want it like this :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
top    |   abei   |    CI  |  pac  |   FRK   | frk1  | frk2  |  frk3  | frk4 |... 
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------
A      |     b    |    e   |   1   |    12   |  13   |  14   |        |      |... 
A      |     c    |    t   |   2   |    45   |  56   |  23   |   29   |   50 |... 
b      |     c    |    t   |   1   |    11   |  56   |  56   |   78   |      |... 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this code but doesn't work!

```
SELECT atop.name AS top, aseco.name AS abei, aseco.abeiId AS CI, aseco.location AS pac, axrt.frk AS FRK,frk1,frk2,frk3,frk4,frk5,frk6,frk7,frk8,frk9,frk10,frk11,frk12, 
    max(case when row=1 then data end) frk1,
    max(case when row=2 then data end) frk2,
    max(case when row=3 then data end) frk3,
    max(case when row=4 then data end) frk4,
    max(case when row=5 then data end) frk5,
    max(case when row=6 then data end) frk6,
    max(case when row=7 then data end) frk7,
    max(case when row=8 then data end) frk8,
    max(case when row=9 then data end) frk9,
    max(case when row=10 then data end) frk10,
    max(case when row=11 then data end) frk11,
    max(case when row=12 then data end) frk12
FROM atop INNER JOIN (aseco INNER JOIN axrt ON (aseco.abeiId = axrt.abeiId) AND (aseco.BCFId = axrt.BCFId) AND (aseco.topId = axrt.topId)) ON atop.topId = aseco.topId
WHERE (((axrt.ctp)<>8) AND ((aseco.abeiish)=5)) OR (((axrt.ctp)<>3) AND ((aseco.abeiish)=2) AND ((aseco.hpnmd)=2));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why do you have both mysql and oracle tagged?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` and you don't need the extra columns in the `select`.  Try this:

```
SELECT atop.name AS top, aseco.name AS abei, aseco.abeiId AS CI, aseco.location AS pac, axrt.frk AS FRK, 
    max(case when row=1 then data end) frk1,
    max(case when row=2 then data end) frk2,
    max(case when row=3 then data end) frk3,
    max(case when row=4 then data end) frk4,
    max(case when row=5 then data end) frk5,
    max(case when row=6 then data end) frk6,
    max(case when row=7 then data end) frk7,
    max(case when row=8 then data end) frk8,
    max(case when row=9 then data end) frk9,
    max(case when row=10 then data end) frk10,
    max(case when row=11 then data end) frk11,
    max(case when row=12 then data end) frk12
FROM atop INNER JOIN
     (aseco INNER JOIN axrt ON (aseco.abeiId = axrt.abeiId) AND (aseco.BCFId = axrt.BCFId) AND (aseco.topId = axrt.topId)) ON atop.topId = aseco.topId
WHERE (((axrt.ctp)<>8) AND ((aseco.abeiish)=5)) OR (((axrt.ctp)<>3) AND ((aseco.abeiish)=2) AND ((aseco.hpnmd)=2))
GROUP BY atop.name, aseco.name, aseco.abeiId, aseco.location ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried It but that returns me an error #1054 - Unknown column 'row' in 'field list'

Comment: can you give any other solution please?

Comment: `row` is in your query.  Why did you use it if it is not in the data?

Comment: I thought it is a variable that will return the number of rows, please can you provide any solution?